# Spring aop, cglib enhanced class lose generic info

Tags: java, json, spring, struts2, cglib

I have a struts 2 action class:

```
public class MyAction{
    private ArrayList<User> users;
    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users){
        this.users = users;
    }
    public String doMyAction(){
        //...
    }
}
```

**the doMyAction method has a AOP pointcut**, so `MyAction` is actually a cglib proxied class at runtime, and the `users` field will be populated by json data from client, when aop is enabled, struts `JSONInterceptor` will fail to populate json data into `users` field. I debuged with the source code of struts json plugin and found this in org.apache.struts2.json.JSONPopulator:

```
public void populateObject(Object object, final Map elements) 
                                                            throws IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IntrospectionException,
            IllegalArgumentException, JSONException, InstantiationException {
        Class clazz = object.getClass();

        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();

        // iterate over class fields
        for (int i = 0; i < props.length; ++i) {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            String name = prop.getName();

            if (elements.containsKey(name)) {
                Object value = elements.get(name);
                Method method = prop.getWriteMethod();

                if (method != null) {
                    JSON json = method.getAnnotation(JSON.class);
                    if ((json != null) && !json.deserialize()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // use only public setters
                    if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                        Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
                        Type[] genericTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

                        if (paramTypes.length == 1) {
                            Object convertedValue = this.convert(paramTypes[0], 
                                                           genericTypes[0], value, method);
                            method.invoke(object, new Object[] { convertedValue });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and on this line:

```
Type[] genericTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();
```

when AOP is enabled, it returns `java.util.ArrayList` against the setter method of `users` field. but `java.util.ArrayList<User>` expected.

It seems that my action class lose it's generic info when proxied by cglib. I also found  [a old bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/cglib/bugs/25/) about this.

I can exclude my method from aop configurations to fix this. but I still want to know if there is a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My idea is try to find the actual type behind the proxy. According to spring documentation, any proxy obtained from spring aop implements the `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised` interface, and this interface expose method to query the target class.

```
Any AOP proxy obtained from Spring can be cast to this interface to allow manipulation of its AOP advice.
```

so here we have a considerable option, we can download the struts json plugin source code and build our own one, with modification on `populateObject` method of `JSONPopulator`

```
public void populateObject(Object object, final Map elements) throws IllegalAccessException,
            InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, IntrospectionException,
            IllegalArgumentException, JSONException, InstantiationException {

        Class clazz = object.getClass();

        // if it is a proxy, find the actual type behind it
        if(Advised.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
            clazz = ((Advised)object).getTargetSource().getTargetClass();
        }

        BeanInfo info = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clazz);
        PropertyDescriptor[] props = info.getPropertyDescriptors();

        // iterate over class fields
        for (int i = 0; i < props.length; ++i) {
            PropertyDescriptor prop = props[i];
            String name = prop.getName();

            if (elements.containsKey(name)) {
                Object value = elements.get(name);
                Method method = prop.getWriteMethod();

                if (method != null) {
                    JSON json = method.getAnnotation(JSON.class);
                    if ((json != null) && !json.deserialize()) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // use only public setters
                    if (Modifier.isPublic(method.getModifiers())) {
                        Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes();


                        Type[] genericTypes = method.getGenericParameterTypes();

                        if (paramTypes.length == 1) {
                            Object convertedValue = this.convert(paramTypes[0], genericTypes[0], value,
                                    method);
                            method.invoke(object, new Object[] { convertedValue });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

please note these lines I added:

```
 // if it is a proxy, find the actual type behind it
            if(Advised.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)){
                clazz = ((Advised)object).getTargetSource().getTargetClass();
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Cglib was created before generic types existed. A proxy is generated as a subclass of the proxied class in cglib which does not retain the generic type information. Therefore, you cannot query it from the proxy class.